# How to check if the content of the nested tags exists or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Suppose I have a structure like this in my div

```
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="addrLabel">Address</div>
<div class="addrValue">

<!-- this content value i want to check if exist, then grab it else no value -->

the content which i want to check if exist or not.  if a single value is there i want to grab it also
  <span class="hrefClass">
      <a href="#">next link</a>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

**Second time I am repeating this div with null value**

```
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="addrLabel">Address</div>
<div class="addrValue">

<!-- no value at all -->
  <span class="hrefClass">
      <a href="#">next link</a>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

How can I achieve this

Comment: the below answer does not solve my problem as i want to check if there is a content then only i want to push

Comment: please provide me solution on each condition if value if no value but 3 answer does not address this

Comment: here is a fiddle which does not enter else condition to push no value present https://jsfiddle.net/ur5fntvp/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this demo... it checks if the `nodeType` of the `contents()` `div.addrValue` is `3 or a text node`

```js
var addrArray = [];
$(".addrValue").each(function(ndx, elem) {
  var text = $(elem).contents()
    .filter(function() {
      if (this.nodeType === 3) { // chech for text node
        if ($(this).text().trim().length !== 0) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }).text();
  if (text.length === 0) { // check string length
    addrArray.push('no value at all');
  } else {
    addrArray.push(text.trim());
  }

});

console.log(addrArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="addrLabel">Address</div>
  <div class="addrValue">

    <!-- this content value i want to check if exist, then grab it else no value -->

    the content which i want to check if exist or not. if a single value is there i want to grab it also
    <span class="hrefClass">
      <a href="#">next link</a>
  </span>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<div class="mainDiv">
  <div class="addrLabel">Address</div>
  <div class="addrValue">


    <span class="hrefClass">
      <a href="#">next link</a>
  </span>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `.text()` equals `false`. Like this:

```
var addrArray = [];

if($('.addrValue').text() != false)
{
    addrArray.push($(this).text());
}else{
    addrArray.push('no value present');
}
```

Check the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ur5fntvp/

**EDIT**
You can also use `.html()` method instead of `.text()`. It depends on whether you want to get all HTML tags or text only

Comment: i want to push no value present if there is no value but your code fails to do so here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ur5fntvp/4/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

 var a  = $('.addrValue').text()
 
 if(a.length) {
   console.log('exists')  
 } else {
   console.log("doesn't exists")  
 }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="addrLabel">Address</div>
<div class="addrValue">

<!-- this content value i want to check if exist, then grab it else no value -->

the content which i want to check if exist or not.  if a single value is there i want to grab it also
  <span class="hrefClass">
      <a href="#">next link</a>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```